# Container managed transaction boundary in SFSB

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, stateful-session-bean

I have read in the book that:

> Typically, the container begins a transaction immediately before an enterprise bean method starts. It commits the transaction just before the method exits.

Suppose my stateful EJB has exposed 3 business methods and the client calls these 3 methods sequentially and want wants to run these 3 methods within a single transaction. These methods would be called across multiple requests.

Now the spec says that the transaction is committed just before the method exits. How will I be able to rollback the whole transaction, if my 1st method is successful and 2nd (or 3rd) method fails?

Please note that I don't want to use create my own transaction boundary.

Any help or the pointer in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a stateful session bean to act as a buffer. And you want a transaction around multiple calls.

From a design perspective, it's OK, if the transaction is started and committed/rollbacked from a *single* request (from within a single `HttpServletRequest` for example). In this case you can use a `UserTransaction` to span the transaction over multiple calls to an EJB. But a `UserTransaction` is bound to the current thread, so it might be difficult to pass it to the next request.

If you start and commit from *different* requests, you lose control over the duration of the transaction: Now a client controls the transaction. If that client crashes, the transaction won't be rolled back until the transaction timeout is reached. So the recommendation in this case is to buffer in a `HttpSession` for example. If all data has been collected, call a (stateless) EJB to persist it.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Although I did not want to use UserTransaction, it seems I am left with no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the bean that calls all the other 3 methods. Then they'll be in the same transaction.

Comment: I can do that but the thing is that those method would be called across multiple requests.

Comment: @user2306993 Regarding "across multiple requests": That changes the question/answer,  I've added it to your question.

Comment: @Beryllium thanks.
Is there a way through which I could signal the container that start the transaction the way you do but commit the data only if I say explicitly?

Comment: @user2306993 This possibly works using a `UserTransaction`. I've posted an answer.